# Multiple functions apply on single button click

Tags: java, android, android-button

I am trying to apply a function on a button that when I press first time then `Function1` show image in imageView2 and when we press it again (second time) then `Function2` show other image (replace image of Function1) in imageView2 , for that I try the below logic , but it only work on (count==1) .

```
private int count = 0;        
Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextButton);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)  {
        if (count==1)
        {
                grayimg(bmInImg.getHeight(),bmInImg.getWidth(), mPhotoIntArray, mCannyOutArray); 
                Bitmap bmOutImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);  
                bmOutImg.setPixels(mCannyOutArray, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight());
                imageview_2.setImageBitmap(bmOutImg);
        }
        else if(count==2)
        {
               grayimg_2(bmInImg.getHeight(),bmInImg.getWidth(), mPhotoIntArray, mCannyOutArray); 
                Bitmap bmOutImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);  
                bmOutImg.setPixels(mCannyOutArray, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight());
                imageview_2.setImageBitmap(bmOutImg);
        }
        else if(count==3)
        {
               grayimg_3(bmInImg.getHeight(),bmInImg.getWidth(), mPhotoIntArray, mCannyOutArray); 
                Bitmap bmOutImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);  
                bmOutImg.setPixels(mCannyOutArray, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight());
                imageview_2.setImageBitmap(bmOutImg);
        }
        count++;            
    }
});
```

Comment: you mean `count == 2` is never true? that's impossible.

Comment: Count was initialized to 0..on first click nothing happens as there was no function call for count==0..on second click count is becoming 1 and calling the function 1.."try initialize with 1"

Comment: else if(count==2) is not working

Comment: use an array then if (count >= arr.length) count = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this -

```
    Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
    public void onClick(View v)  {

         if (imageView1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
             imageView1..setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             imageView2..setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
         else
         {
             imageView1..setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             imageView2..setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         }         

        }
        });
```

Comment: then what for count==3 ?

Comment: Its not about count its about visibility on condition. On every click just check if something is visible/invisible and accordingly set your next view visibility/invisibility.

Comment: I have constant imageview1 and i want to change imageview2 on every click

Comment: You just follow this logic don't think of count way. It should work.

Comment: where to declare my function ?

Comment: No need to declare any function do this within on your onclick.

Comment: Its just making image1 invisible and show image2 when i call it , but its not showing my 2nd function

Comment: while changing the imagevisibility change the function call. show 1st image call first method next click show second image call second function thats it

Answer (score 0):

Set the following

```
private int count = 1;
```

as the first time button is pressed count = 0 and does not enter both if or else if block and is incremented to count = 1 and then pressed again first if block is executed.

If you want alternating effect do the following

```
private boolean chk = true;        
Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextButton);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)  {
       if (chk)
       {
          // Function1
       }
       else 
       {
          // Function2
       }
       chk = !chk;          

    }
});
```

Comment: then what for if(count==3) ? and yes I tried as count=1 initialization

Comment: @MarcoAcierno This is what I am saying , my question is not limited to one or two click

Comment: @Munieb I see no reason why the count wont work unless count is being is altered in those functions or else where

Comment: @sujithvm I am calling function from `jni` , native android

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
private int count = 0;        
Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextButton);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)  {
        if ((count%2) == 0)
        {
            // Function2
        }
        else
        {
           // Function1
        }
        count++;          

    }
    });
```

count % 2 calculates to zero if it is even number otherwise count is odd number. Now you can call functions accordingly...